# Why does a merge in Eclipse say there are no changes found when I know for sure that there are changes?

Tags: svn, eclipse, merge

I have checked out a copy of my code and have the version that I want to merge to.

What I do is:

1. Right click my working copy
2. Go to Team>Merge and then select the newer code

and click ok it'll go through the motions and then say no changes found

Comment: I'm mainly wondering if I'm missing some step.

Comment: Can we see the portion of the code you are changing?

Comment: Sorry it was so late of a reply, I just noticed this was still open. It wasn't merging because the revision numbers got mixed up.